# PHP exceptions try and catch

Tags: php, pdo

If I were to do the following:

```
$pds= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo  WHERE   username=:username AND   password=:password");

$pds->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));

$row = $pds->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Do I need to put a try {} for each command executed, or will a try block cover the entire code, with a single catch block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you would need to do for the query you are doing is:

```
try{
  $pds= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo  WHERE   username=:username AND   password=:password");
  $pds->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
  die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
  //Or Echo, or store in a variable to process if you don't want to die()
}

$row = $pds->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:
Also, if you want a bit more separation and readability for building a query you can try creating a query parameter array instead of creating the array directly in the execute() function.

```
$pds = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username=:username AND   password=:password");
$query_params = array(
  ':username' => $username,
  ':password' => $password
);
$result = $pds->execute($query_params);
```

Comment: @thetao I wonder why did you choose the most improper way that ever can be.

Comment: Did you try this approach yourself?

Comment: I do use the try{prepare(); execute();}catch(PDOException $ex){} and it seems to work fine with me, are you implying that PDOexception is the wrong catch to use? Or that the prepare and execute is wrong?

Comment: Look. Wrapping every query into dedicated try-catch is a huge waste of time and space. I can't believe someone would write tens and hundreds blocks around every query. Moreover - it is useless. If you get rid of this block from this code, you will have way *better* error handling.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you for the insight and I will definitely look in to it more and get a better understanding. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 5):

> Do I need to put a try {} for each command executed, or will a try block cover the entire code,

## Neither.

Here goes a set of **proper** rules right from the real life:

- use try/catch for the single command or set of commands **only** in case of

  - you're going to handle **the error itself**. Frankly, if you have an **action** to do in case of error: to rollback a transaction, for example.
  - error is non-fatal - to bypass it
- all other exceptions have to be handled by [exception handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php), not global try/catch block.

though you can omit the latter one, as PHP has built-in basic handler that works better than one an inexperienced programmer can develop.

Comment: Seeing that post again since a time. Funny how this was getting upvoted 5 times. The phrase `only if you're going to handle the error itself` is the only half-way correct statement here. What if you want to create a custom Exception for upper levels, meaning levels which can handle the situation? Something like `DupKeyException`? That's a common task, as PDO will throw only PDOExceptions. Do you wan't upper levels to handle SQL error states, and driver errors? :D! You are a vandal, I can't see much common sense here.

Answer (score 0):

A try block will fail catch the first exception that is generated. Therefore it is quite safe to place all 3 statements in the try section.

You can also use multiple catch blocks so that different exception types can be handled differently such as:

```
 try {
      $pds= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo  WHERE   username=:username AND   password=:password");
      $pds->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));
      $row = $pds->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'A pdo exception happened';
 } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'A different exception happened';
 }
```

This helps ensure you can for example clean up after the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely study error handling. Also, you should do a little research (at least on stackoverflow) before posting this type of questions.

You can put that code inside a single try block.

```
try
{
$pds= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo  WHERE   username=:username AND       password=:password");

$pds->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));

$row = $pds->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{


}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need only to place a `try{}` block around the all code, and catch it with a single `catch{}` block.
See the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

As all of the methods will potentially throw the **same** exception: `PDOException` it could make sense to wrap each call it is own `try/catch` block. Yes, this is a good idea if you need to react depending on which method throws the exception and don't to parse the exception's `errorInfo` and/or `errorCode` (which will be driver dependend)

Answer (score -1):

One try/catch block means, if you get exception on first statement, remaining ones will not be executed, which is obvious to do in your case here.

In future if you have a different situation, your choice can be different too.